# Writing math equation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How would I write this equation in JavaScript?

http://s32.postimg.org/m0jchfqlw/CALCULATIONS.jpg

This is my attempt at programming it, but I'm sure it's wrong.

```
var MIR = parseFloat(($('#aprrate').val() / 100) / 12);
var paymentAmount = (MIR * $('#amounttofinance').val())/(1 - Math.pow((1 + MIR), -$('#numberofpayments').val()));
$('#paymentamount').val(paymentAmount);
```

EDIT: It shows NaN in the paymentamount textbox.

If I try this..

```
var MIR = parseFloat((parseFloat($('#aprrate').val()) / 100) / 12);
var paymentAmount = (MIR * parseFloat($('#amounttofinance').val()))/(1 - Math.pow((1 + MIR), -parseInt($('#numberofpayments'),10).val()));
$('#paymentamount').val(paymentAmount);
```

I get nothing, completely blank.

Comment: *"but I'm sure it's wrong"* How do you know? What exactly is wrong?

Comment: Looks fine.  Is there a problem with the result?

Comment: Looks fine to me, why do you think it's wrong? You could just divide by 1200 in your opening line BTW.

Comment: Shows NaN, but if I try doing things like parseFloat and parseInt to make sure it's in the right format, it ends up blank.

Comment: I would calculate each part separately, do your nominator and denominator separately and output the values to the console. Ensure that the values you are trying to read are numeric values, of course.

Comment: Some values entered into this equation will result in NaN. Entering 0 for either numberofpayments or aprrate, for example will result in NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missplaced your .val() at the end of the second line.
Can you try this :

```
var MIR = parseFloat((parseFloat($('#aprrate').val()) / 100) / 12);
var paymentAmount = (MIR * parseFloat($('#amounttofinance').val()))/(1 - Math.pow((1 + MIR), -parseInt($('#numberofpayments').val(),10)));
$('#paymentamount').val(paymentAmount);
```

Comment: You are awesome! That fixed it!